# Change Endpoint in Azure Devops Invoke Rest API task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to invoke another endpoint for my task but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone know of a way to do that?

The endpoint that Devops defaults to:
https://management.Azure.com

The desired endpoint:
https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms

The documentation is not really clear whether this is at all possible.. or at least I can´t find it..

Resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

Comment: What was the issue you were getting? You can first try in postman, and then it should work in pipeline.

Comment: I tried it in Postman. It works like a charm, though in Devops the endpoint always uses https://management.Azure.com. However, the enpoint should be changed to https://germanywestcentral.api.azureml.ms ... Is that possible?!

Comment: Can you remove the in-private information and share your pipeline definition if possible(YAML or JSON file)?

Comment: I am using an azure function instead. I cannot share the pipeline since it´s a approval and checks job, only available via the UI. thanks